# Preferable way to fetch data from sub-components

Tags: angular, angular2-template

imagine, I have two components `Parent` and `Child`. `Child` is used to collect user input that `Parent` will need at a later time.

Right now I'm thinking of two ways to accomplish this:

Option 1:

```
<child-component [data]="childData" (done)="onDone()"></child-component>
```

Parent basically passes `childData = {}` to `Child`. `Child` writes stuff into `data` making it available in `Parent`'s `childData` and emit `done` when done.

Option 2:

```
<child-component (done)="onDone(data)"></child-component>
```

`Child` emits `done` and the corresponding data when done.

Option 2 seems to better follow the concept of angular2 imho, but option 1 makes data available right away. Would you consider option 1 bad practice?

Also is there another option which I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 3):

To be truly stand alone component, the parent should not be reacting to the done, The done should do something to the dataModel which the parent watches and reacts due to an update triggered.

To me that is a cleaner way of implementing the parent child relationship. **Reason being when the child changes every parent using the child will need to understand what done has changed to, but if done happens inside a child and the parent can interpret it from another source common to both parent and child then both parent and child are loosely coupled.**

It is a matter of choice in this case, both your options and mine should do the trick, **it depends on what type of application you are building, if you are building a light weight application you can get away with any model,** but as the application comes larger these parent child dependencies will come back to bite us.